# Cross platform/compiler consistent sprintf of floating point numbers

Tags: c++, lua, printf, string-formatting

We have a game that needs to be deterministic as it is part of its multiplayer model. We also use Lua, which uses the `sprintf` internally (the format is `%.14g`).

The problem arises when it prints number like 0.00001. In some cases it prints `1e-05` and in some other cases, it prints `1e-005` (extra zero).

For example when compiled with Visual studio 2015 it prints `1e-005`, and with Visual studio 2013 it prints `1e-05`. I tried different locale settings, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

The question is: *What is the best solution to achieve deterministic results?*
I don't really care if the scientific notation is standardized, or eliminated.

Solutions I thought about:

- When I use the `%f` notation, it doesn't ignore the insignificant zeroes, so having `%.14f` would result into impractically long numbers.
- Using custom `sprintf` method (copy pasted from some of the standard libraries)
- Using some special format I didn't thought about (I use only this as reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: I have solved a similar problem in the past by using `sprintf` into a buffer and then doing some string processing on it. Very hokey, but it worked for me at the time.

Comment: Why do you care for this? What process in your game depends on whether you have an additional zero?

Comment: The best solution to achieve deterministic results is using integer numbers.  But you can also use hexafloat `%a` format.

Comment: I care about it, as the determinism needs to be complete all the time. Any difference can lead to bigger difference etc. We also have control mechanisms that we use to detect the difference as soon as possible, so even if the change doesn't really affect the game, it alerts these mechanisms. (Similar to removing compiler warnings).

Comment: Logicrat: Yes, find and replace of "1e-00"->"1e-0" would probably solve it, but it would be pretty ineffective.

Comment: Egor Skriptunoff: The result is meant to be readable by humans, which hexafloat isn't

Comment: So you don't want it to have an extra zero on some machines, but it's for humans to read? Seems a bit pointless to fix.

Comment: I want it to be a) Human readable b) The same on all machines.

Comment: The `printf` documentation you linked states that `%g` is: 'Use the shortest representation: %e or %f'. So its already non-deterministic by design and allows for a lot of flexibility in the implementation. Did you try to use `%e` alone? Or not specifying a width? I'm a little bit worried that the string representation of a float value causes desynchronization issues, though... That should not happen ... ever... So maybe you should consider changing your data-format to something that does not depend on ascii representation of values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A  year later, this is how we solved it.

We downloaded custom print implementation (trio) and forced usage of this implementation instead of the system one in the lua (and our sources).

We also had to change

```
long double trio_long_double_t;
```

to

```
double trio_long_double_t;
```

in the triodef.h to ensure the Visual studio and linux/mac gives the same results.

Answer (score 18):

You can switch to [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/luajit.html). It formats numbers consistently between platforms.

From the [extensions page](http://luajit.org/extensions.html):

> ### tostring() etc. canonicalize NaN and ±Inf
>
> All number-to-string conversions consistently convert non-finite numbers to the same strings on all platforms. NaN results in "nan", positive infinity results in "inf" and negative infinity results in "-inf".
>
> ### tonumber() etc. use builtin string to number conversion
>
> All string-to-number conversions consistently convert integer and floating-point inputs in decimal and hexadecimal on all platforms. strtod() is not used anymore, which avoids numerous problems with poor C library implementations. The builtin conversion function provides full precision according to the IEEE-754 standard, it works independently of the current locale and it supports hex floating-point numbers (e.g. 0x1.5p-3).

Comment: Yes, this is what we are planning to do for sure. But not in stabilisation release :)

Answer (score 4):

The most voted answer is wrong, because the documentation is wrong in first place.

This is what's happening in LuaJIT:

```
#define lua_number2str(s,n)sprintf((s),"%.14g",(n))
#define lua_str2number(s,p)strtod((s),(p))
```

Looking at `tonumber` and `tostring` implementation those are the macros called to get the results.

Feel free to correct this answer if you find the real "built-in" implementation, cause I'm curious as well to know how it really works.

Answer (score 1):

Lua gives you math.frexp in the standard library. You can use this to split your floats into exponent and mantissa form, and then do a custom print in pure Lua that will not depend on the underlying platform. Here is an example:

```
m,e = math.frexp(val)
io.write(m)
io.write('E')
io.write(e)
```

PS Enjoying the Friday Facts, keep 'em coming :)

Comment: But this doesn't solve that problem, I want to change it by changing the C++ implementation of lua internals, as I can't force people to use it everywhere.

Comment: I thought you solved this - you already had an accepted answer when I answered 1.5 years ago. This is a solution that you could ship as lua code -e.g. add a "standard" function to format numbers to the interpreter in your game. Or, you could get the same affect by changing the lua implementation. But they both solve the problem getting deterministic float output on all platforms.